# Data Container Quick Access

Tags: c#, header, stream, containers, data-storage

What is the best way to store data (no serialization - just using a Stream + BinaryWriter/BinaryReader) in this scenario for quick and easy access to files.

DataContainer contains 10 files each files is 1 mb.

If I need to write to/read from file 5 it should only read that part of the 10 mb container and return 1mb by using a unique name/ID identifier, possibly stored in a header. Problems occur when you wish to update a file in the middle of the container, because the indexs will change in the stream (if the updated object is larger or smaller than the existing one)

How do I handle this without having to rewrite the entire datacontainer when updating?

I wish to write this for myself instead of using pre-existing libraries.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can store sizes of files instead of indexes, so you can calculate indexes. For example, consider container:
file  size
1     10
2     15
3     20
4     25
Index of file 4 is calculated simply as 10+15+20.

Comment: Sure, but I wish to have one file containing multiple files and I should only have to read what I want from it, so if the file contains 100 files I should only have to read 1 file without reading all 99 other files. So how do you calculate file size for an object, also how do you push objects in the stream to a certain position, cause if file #5 is 1000 bytes, starts at 5000, file #6 is at 6000 but when file #5 is updated to 1500 files, file #6 needs to be pushed to 6500.